C++ Error: invalid conversion from 'long long int (*)()' to 'long long int (*)(int)'
I am trying to wrap a call of WinAPI function in the function that will automatically check for an error:
template<typename T = void,typename function, typename ...Args>
T winapi_wrapper(function caller, Args&&... args)
{
    static_assert(not std::is_function_v<function>);
    auto check_error = [](){ GetLastError() != 0 ? throw std::runtime_error{"error in a WinAPI call"}  : [](){}();};
    if constexpr(!std::is_void_v<T>)
    {
       T result = caller(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
       check_error();
       return result;
    }
    else
    {
       caller(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
       check_error();
    }
}
int main()
{
   using func_zero_args = long long (__cdecl*)();
   using func_one_arg = long long (__cdecl*)(int);
   std::unique_ptr<HINSTANCE__, decltype(&FreeLibrary)> dll_handler{winapi_wrapper<HINSTANCE>(&LoadLibraryA,"C:/test.dll"), FreeLibrary};
   func_zero_args no_arg_ptr = winapi_wrapper<func_zero_args>(&GetProcAddress, dll_handler.get(), "func_no_args");
   func_one_arg one_arg_ptr = winapi_wrapper<func_one_arg>(&GetProcAddress, dll_handler.get(), "one_arg_fn");
}

The first call works as expected, but the second one is not compiling with the following error:
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'long long (*)(int)' with an rvalue of type 'long long (*)()': different number of parameters (1 vs 0)
I tried to change the type of func_one_arg
int main()
{
   using func_zero_args = long long (__cdecl*)();
   using func_one_arg = void (__cdecl*)();
   std::unique_ptr<HINSTANCE__, decltype(&FreeLibrary)> dll_handler{winapi_wrapper<HINSTANCE>(&LoadLibraryA,"C:/test.dll"), FreeLibrary};
   func_zero_args no_arg_ptr = winapi_wrapper<func_zero_args>(&GetProcAddress, dll_handler.get(), "func_no_args");
   func_one_arg one_arg_ptr = winapi_wrapper<func_one_arg>(&GetProcAddress, dll_handler.get(), "one_arg_fn");
}

So now the error is:
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'void (*)()' with an rvalue of type 'long long (*)()': different return type ('void' vs 'long long')

A [mre] could be int main() {   using func_one_arg = long long(__cdecl*)(int);   func_one_arg result = GetProcAddress(nullptr, "one_arg_fn"); }

Cannot reproduce. Please post a [mre]. Do not edit out any #include directives.

@n.m.couldbeanAI godbolt.org/z/nhP5jsvsq

It looks like you expect GetProcAddress to return results of different types depending on what string you pass to it. It doesn't work this way.

The result of GetProcAddress will always need to be cast to the actual type (assuming that the actual type is something other than FARPROC's "void (WINAPI *)()", which generally seems a safe assumption). Even where that assumption fails, the cast from FARPROC to FARPROC would do no harm.

The problem was the fact, that GetProcAddress returns a pointer to long long, when I was writing this wrapper I missed that, so the solution is to cast the result to type T
template<typename T = void,typename function, typename ...Args>
T winapi_wrapper(function caller, Args&&... args)
{
    static_assert(not std::is_function_v<function>);
    auto check_error = [](){ GetLastError() != 0 ? throw std::runtime_error{"error in a WinAPI call"}  : [](){}();};
    if constexpr(!std::is_void_v<T>)
    {
       T result = (T)caller(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
       check_error();
       return result;
    }
    else
    {
       caller(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
       check_error();
    }
}

